# Accessing Powercfg device details

Tags: windows, sleep, powercfg

I am trying to add my keyboard to the wake list (no such option is available through device manager). I used this command in cmd

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any

Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft)
Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
PCI Express Downstream Switch Port
PCI Express Downstream Switch Port (001)
PCI Express Downstream Switch Port (002)
Realtek(R) Audio
Killer E3100X 2.5 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Microsoft Input Configuration Device
Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator
Intel(R) PCI Express Root Port #17 - 06C0
USB Input Device
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (001)
USB Composite Device (003)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (002)
HID-compliant mouse (001)
HID Keyboard Device
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (006)
USB Input Device (003)
WDC PC SN530 SDBPNPZ-512G-1032
Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)
Intel(R) USB 3.1 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft) (001)
ACPI Lid
Intel(R) PCI Express Root Port #15 - 06B6
I2C HID Device
Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)
Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
Standard NVM Express Controller
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
HID-compliant consumer control device (002)
High Definition Audio Controller
PCI Express Upstream Switch Port
NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller
HID-compliant mouse (002)
Intel(R) PCI Express Root Port #9 - 06B0
Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Thunderbolt(TM) Controller - 15E8
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (010)
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) (001)
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) (002)
Intel(R) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901
Intel(R) Display Audio
HID-compliant touch pad
HID-compliant system controller (002)
USB Input Device (009)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (013)
NVIDIA USB 3.10 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.10 (Microsoft)
```

I realize there is a hid compliant keyboard there, but I believe that is a usb keyboard I connected a while ago. The laptops own keyboard should be Steelseries Ps/2

[image]

This listed 20-40 items, most of which i cant recognise. Any way to identify these devices? Some hardware id i can cross reference etc?

Comment: What is your keyboard, and can you [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1631055/edit) your post with the output of the `powercfg` command.

Comment: Try  `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` (list of devices currently configured to wake the computer from any sleep state). There should be mouse as well as keyboard…

Comment: @harrymc output added

Comment: PS2 mouse must be able to wake the computer, yet it isn't in the list. One thing I can think of is if the BIOS is blocking it. Try in the BIOS to find, perhaps somewhere like "Settings > Advanced > Wake Up Event Setup" a setting similar to "Resume From S3/S4/S5 by PS/2 Mouse", and ensure that it's enabled. Look also for some setting in the Steelseries Engine.

Comment: @harrymc why mouse? also, you dont think its possible that the keyboard is named as some random think on that list?

Comment: Sorry, mistype, I meant keyboard.